# Quartz cronExpression from database in Grails

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have added quartz:1.0.2 plugin in my grails:2.4.4 application.

What I want to achieve is set the cronExpression value form database.

I have created a job named myBatch from grails-command. Inside the myBatchJob.groovy's trigger block, if I try to fetch any data from database, it doesn't allow.

I also tried adding following in BootStrap.groovy

```
def quartzScheduler
def init = { servletContext ->
    CronTrigger trigger = quartzScheduler.getTrigger("myBatchJobTrigger","DEFAULT")

    def conf_expr = Configuration.findByConfigKey("batch_job_config_expression").configValue

    trigger.setCronExpression '${conf_expr}'
    quartzScheduler.rescheduleJob (trigger.getName(), trigger.getGroup(), trigger)
}
```

But it gives me this error

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.quartz.impl.StdScheduler.getTrigger() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

Here in the above code, Configuration is the domain with two fields configKey and configValue. And I also imported `org.quartz.CronTrigger` but no luck.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `triggers closure` from your job file. Then in `BootStrap.groovy` you can fetch the `cron expression` from database and schedule your job using the dynamic schedular methods. For example your `BootStrap.groovy init` closure can be like the following

```
    Configuration config = Configuration.findByConfigKey("batch_job_config_expression")
    MyBatchJob.schedule(config.configValue)
```

For more on dynamic scheduling http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-quartz/guide/triggers.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am getting this error: `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener - Error initializing the application: No such property: MyBatchJob for class: BootStrap`. And it's not allowing import of MyBatchJob in BootStrap. Any idea?

Comment: *Not allowing import `MyBatchJob`*, what do you mean by this?

Comment: Means if I try to import `myapp.MyBatchJob`, it gives error that the class not found. The file path is `grails-app/jobs/myapp/MyBatchJob.groovy`. What could be the problem?

Comment: Well can you post the codes of your `MyBatchJob.groovy` and `BootStrap.groovy`? With full `package` and `import` statements. You can update your question. Otherwise I don't have any clue why a simple `import` would not work as grails or quartz-plugin has nothing to do with that

Comment: Please check these URLs: [BootStrap.groovy](http://imgur.com/ib4EJ5v) and [MyBatchJob.groovy](http://imgur.com/aLgON0R). Error can be seen in the console below.

Comment: I don't see any `import` statement for `MyBatchJob` in your `BootStrap`. Add `import sample1.MyBatchJob` in your `BootStrap.groovy`

Comment: Strange!! [Added import](http://imgur.com/H3EKgjs) shows error but it runs all right. Due to this I was thinking that it's not able to find the MyBatchJob class. This is why you can't be fully dependent on the IDEs all the time. Thanks a lot!!